# Save ARKit scene to backend and load later?

Tags: swift, ios11, swift4, arkit

Apologizing in advance if my question is not phrased correctly; as I am new to AR technology, and a student in CS. I've been reading about AR all day, and I haven't been able to answer my question yet.

My question is: With ARKit from Apple, would we be able to load an ARKit scene, or session from a backend to recognize the plane it was created on? The perfect example is the Babysitter app in the WWDC demo. Could I create drawings on a surface at my house, save that session to a backend, and then when the babysitter comes over, it would download the session data from the cloud, and load the drawings in the positions in which they were saved?

Again, sorry if I butchered the question, I'm not experienced enough to ask this correctly yet.

Comment: Did you get any concrete solution on this? I've the similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** In "ARKit 2" aka ARKit for iOS 12, you can indeed save and restore AR session state. See [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49180032/957768), [the WWDC18 talk on ARKit 2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/602/), or [Apple's ARKit docs and sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit).

The problem with any sort of shared AR — be that two or more devices seeing the same experience at the same time, or one device making a recording for someone else (or even the original device) to experience later — is that such things require a shared frame of reference. That is, the coordinates `0,0,0` need to refer to the same real-world position (and orientation) for both users.

Everything ARKit does is in a frame of reference relative to where your device was when you started the session, and it doesn’t offer a way to localize that frame of reference against any sort of “absolute” world coordinates. That is, if you try to record an experience where you’ve placed some virtual content at, say, `0.2, -0.1, -0.5`, the only way someone playing back that experience later will see that content at the same real-world position is if the second person is standing in the exact same place, holding their device at the same height, and pointed in the same direction.

The Giphy “notes for babysitter” demo [that made the press a few weeks ago](https://techcrunch.com/2017/08/29/a-preview-of-the-first-wave-of-ar-apps-coming-to-iphones/) seems to mostly be about recording *video* of an AR experience.

AR with a shared (or “absolute”) frame of reference might be possible, but it’s not something ARKit does right out of the box.

Comment: Agreed with this, I have been working on an app where the AR state needs to be persisted between sessions for multiple operators to use, the only way I was able to achieve a basic prototype was to mount 4 strategic camera in the room and create a digital blueprint of the room I was currently in and then use location + the 4 cameras to provide an estimated x,y position for me in the room, in short I don't think it's easily achievable yet and even the approach I took felt extremely over engineered, I'm sure this is something that will improve drastically in the coming months/years

Comment: Thanks @Alex and rickster . This made a lot more sense than the resources I could find on Google! I guess I'll look more into it, and see if I can hack something together with CoreLocation and ARKit. It may not be an exact fit of the landscape, but can probably pin an AR scene to a location for now!

Comment: Be aware that Core Location and ARKit operate on different scales. AR positioning accuracy is on the scale of millimeters to centimeters; Geo positioning has error on the scale of one to several meters.

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to get a single shared point of reference by doing some calibration with real-world markers placed in the room?

Comment: @kymer Possibly — at least, that’s one of the avenues people have been exploring.

Answer (score 0):

Another method which seems to be working is comparing point clouds positions.
If 2 players are looking at some surface which has a similar pattern then you can define it as a new point of reference. 
I've did some experiments, and it seems to work - but it's not that reliable.
Now I am testing new approach with photogrammetry where the original mesh of environment is being stored in the cloud and compared to one from the camera.

Comment: What do you mean by "point of reference"? Can you be more precise about what you where trying to do?
Can you sort of "edit" the point of reference for ARKit? Maybe from the Core Location Position?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by scan a qr code as an anchor.

https://github.com/eugenebokhan/ARKit-Multiplayer